# Access google docs using gspread

Tags: python, google-docs-api

I am trying to access google docs using gspread utility , I was successful when i tried below code on my google doc

```
import gspread        
g = gspread.login('gmailID', 'password')
worksheet = g.open('GoogleSheetName').get_worksheet(0)          
val = worksheet.cell(2, 1).value       
print val
```

But when I tried same code for my corporate account which uses google server, I am getting below error:

```
  raise AuthenticationError("Unable to authenticate. %s code" % ex.code)
gspread.exceptions.AuthenticationError: Unable to authenticate. 500 code
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: It's been awhile since I used gspread, but I remember something about it not working if two factor auth is enabled on the google account.   I can't seem to find where I read about that though.  Best of luck.

Comment: In the interim, maybe share the spreadsheet(s) with a regular google account and authenticate with those credentials

Answer (score 0):

See what the author of gspread says [here](https://github.com/burnash/gspread):

> Two Factor Authorization
>
> In case your Google Account protected with Two Factor Authorization,
>   you have to create an application-specific password and use your email
>   to login as usual.
>
> Otherwise you will get an AuthenticationError: Unable to authenticate.
>   403 code when trying to login.